# How to set website to not rotate in ipad

Tags: ipad, web, rotation

I have a quick question... I have googled it but have found nothing that can help me. I  have a website I am creating and I do not want it to rotate in an ipad. Is there anyway to achieve this? I just want it to stay horizontal. Thanks in advance for any direction to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there will be, the rotation is based in the iPad's iOS. Maybe notify the user to switch on the rotation lock?